# Geohash using decimal

Tags: algorithm, geohash

I'm quite new to spatial data processing and got to work with some existing legacy data which isnt well documented. I see that in the SQL database geohash values stored along with lat and lon but they aren't characters but long decimals... For example `27944766710` corresponds to `49.63304` `6.21676`.

Wonder if anyone has an idea (an algorithm or a formula) how this geohash values encoded/decoded?

Comment: If you really have geohash values they are documented in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geohash.

Comment: the column name in SQL table is `geohash`, but online converters or R package geohash are unable to decode those properly (into the same lat/lon as in the table's row), so i'm puzzled... maybe i need to use binary format of that decimal long value...

Comment: Using one converter for standard geohashes 27944766710 corresponds to -24.94269244, -167.24165373 and not what you report, so you need to tell us more about what database you are using and how the locations where geohashed. There are plenty of websites that discuss GeoHashing but as user30184 says: do you really have geohash values

Comment: thanks! the database is a custom dump of Flightradar24 data, and I do believe that it is geohash value... Im trying to sift through other code, but with no luck so far... I did check Wiki and googled thoroughly and I see folks mentioning decimals, for example here in the "Efficiency" section https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geohash-36 ...